# after completion of doing its functionality my application rerenders and puts hooks onto their default values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So After days of research I pinned the restart as commiting after completion of a full render.All my code does what its suppose to do exactly;but,afterwords it re renders,with all states set back to its initial value.I have tried numerous things such as

1. using memo and pure component
2. deleting components to check which are the ones causing trouble.
3. going through the the cycle via debugging

I also fixed some newb related errors, like having set hooks in conditionals and loops.

I have also tried

- changing classes to functions.
  but no matter how I look at it I cant find what I'm doing wrong. I thought a pair of fresh eyes would help.

menu.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from 'axios';
import { default as AreaW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as CityW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
import { default  as CountryW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as NeighborhoodW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
import { default as RegionW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";
import { NavBar } from "../Navbar/navbar.jsx";
import  {MenuList}  from "./MenuList.jsx";
import GeographicLocationSearch from "./geographicSearchBar.jsx";
import  NewObject  from "./newObject.jsx";
import { ThemeProvider } from "react-bootstrap";

function Menu(props){
   
    
        
    let [supra,setSupra]=useState([]);
    let [options,setOptions]=useState([]);
    let [searchBar,setSearchBar]=useState([{locations:["country","region","area","city","neighborhood"]}]);
    let [category,setCategory]=useState('country');
    let [value,setValue]=useState('');
  
    
    let handleSearchBar=(e)=>{
        
        if(e.category==='country'){
            setCategory((category)=>{let newValue='region';console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
         
         }
          setOptions((options)=>{let newValue=e.kids;console.log(newValue);return newValue;}); 
         setSupra((supra)=>{let newValue=e;console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
         
   

        } 
        
        let handleNavBar=(e)=>{
                setCategory((category)=>{let newValue=e;console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
               setSupra((supra)=>{let newValue=[];console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
                getChildren(category);
             
        }
        const getChildren=(value)=>{
           let ofList=[];
            let res=axios.get('http://localhost:8080/'+value)
                .then
                (  
                    
                    function(res){
                        let list=res.data;
                    if(list.length===0){
                        console.log("");
                    }
                    else{
                            if(list[0]!==undefined){
                                ofList=list;setOptions(options=>{let newValue=ofList;console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
                            }
                        
                        }
                    })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
                

                
            
        }
        
            useEffect(() => {}
                , [value]);
 
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <NavBar content={searchBar} handleNavBar={handleNavBar} />
            </div>
            <div>
            { /*this is the call */}
               <GeographicLocationSearch handleSearchBar={handleSearchBar}/>
            
                <NewObject {...supra}/>
                
           
                 <MenuList Items={options} kind={category}/>
            </div>
               
           
        </div>
        
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

A child component that calls the function i use which after processing refreshes the application.
geographic search

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

import Autocomplete from "../Util/autocomplete.jsx";
import axios from "axios";
import { breakWord } from "./breakWord.js";
// Bootstrap CSS
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import OutsideClickHandler from 'react-outside-click-handler';
class GeographicLocationSearch extends Component {
 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list:[],
      action:"",
      filterList:[],
      currentValue:"",
      tags:[],
      nameToId:[],
      category:"",
      id:0,
      currentValue:""
    };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
    //to filter list
    filterList(){
      let oldList=this.state.list;
      let newList=[];
      if(oldList.length>1){

        oldList.map((e)=>{
          
        if(e.name.startsWith(this.state.currentValue)){
          newList.push(e.name);
        }

        });
      }
      else{
        newList=[];
      }

      this.setState({filterList:newList});
    }
//upon input change.
async onChange(childData){
 
  
  await this.setState({currentValue:childData});
  await this.filterList();
  await this.setState({isInvisible:false});
}
//when value of search bar is decided and a query to submit has been made page will load to specific location.

    async handleSearch(){
       //implement key value pairs in wrapper.
       let possibleOptions=[];
       //set possible options
       let line=this.state.currentValue;
       let value;
       let asCategory=-1;
       let fromList=this.state.list;
       
       let item=fromList.find(item => item.name === line);
       //create object and return it.
       this.props.handleSearchBar(item);
    }
    
    //to generate list
    async componentDidMount(){
      let keyValuePair=[];
      axios.get(
        'http://localhost:8080/'+"country")
           .then(res => {
            Object.values(res).map((item)=>{
              for(let i=0;i<item.length;i++){
    
                keyValuePair.push({'name':breakWord(item[i],'country'),'category':'country',id:item[i].id,'kids':item[i].regions});
              }
             
            })
              
         }).catch(
          
         function (error) {console.log(error)
        }
        );
    
        axios.get(
          'http://localhost:8080/'+"region")
          .then(res => {
            Object.values(res).map((item)=>{
              for(let i=0;i<item.length;i++){
                keyValuePair.push({'name':breakWord(item[i],'region'),'category':'region',id:item[i].id});
              }
             
            })
              
         }).catch(
         function (error) {
        }
        );
    
          axios.get(
            'http://localhost:8080/'+"area")
            .then(res => {
              Object.values(res).map((item)=>{
                for(let i=0;i<item.length;i++){
                  this.keyValuePair.push({'name':breakWord(item[i],'area'),'category':'area',id:item[i].id});
                }
               
              })
                
           }).catch(
           function (error) {
          }
          );
    
          axios.get(
            'http://localhost:8080/'+"city").then(res => {
            Object.values(res).map((item)=>{
              for(let i=0;i<item.length;i++){
                this.keyValuePair.push({'name':breakWord(item[i],'city'),'category':'city',id:item[i].id});
              }
             
            })
              
         }).catch(
         function (error) {
        }
        );
    
        axios.get(
          'http://localhost:8080/'+"neighborhood")
        .then(res => {
          Object.values(res).map((item)=>{
            for(let i=0;i<item.length;i++){
              this.keyValuePair.push({'name':breakWord(item[i],'neighborhood'),'category':'neighborhood',id:item[i].id});
            }
           
          })
            
       }).catch(
       function (error) {
      }
      );
                await this.setState({list:keyValuePair});
                
                
              }
      render() {
        
      
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
              <div>search By Location</div>
              <Autocomplete list={this.state.filterList} onChangeValue={this.onChange}/>
              <input type="submit" value="search Within Location"></input>
            </form>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default GeographicLocationSearch;
```

the last class it reaches before the refresh is a read component.
region main component.

```
import React, {Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from 'axios';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import OutsideClickHandler from 'react-outside-click-handler';
import Autocomplete from '../../Util/autocomplete';
class Region extends Component {
   static propTypes = {
      suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array)
    };
  
    static defaultProps = {
      suggestions: []
    };
    emptyItem={
      value:"",country:""
    }
    //to load data upon generation.
   constructor(props){  
      super(props);  
      this.state = {  
         regionError: ''  ,list:[],
       region:this.emptyItem,regionNames:[""], list:[],
       action:"",
       filterList:[],
       currentValue:"",
       tags:"",
       isInvisible:true
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.filterList=this.filterList.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.onClickAway = this.onClickAway.bind(this);
        this.onGenerate = this.onGenerate.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
      } 
       //to filter list
       async filterList(){
  let newlist=[];
  this.state.list.map((e)=>{
    if(e.startsWith(this.state.currentValue)){
      newlist.concat(e);
    }
   
  }); this.setState({filterList:newlist});
}
//when a tag in a dropbox is clicked current value is the tags value
async onClick(id){
  let newValue=this.state.filterList[id];
  this.setState({currentValue:newValue});
  this.setState({isInvisible:true});
}
//to generate tags
async onGenerate(){
  let newTags="";
  this.state.list.map((e,index)=>{
    
    newTags+=
      '<button id='+index+'  onClick='+this.onClick(index)+'>'+e+'</button>';
  });
  this.setState({tags:newTags});
}
//upon input change.
async onChange(event){
 
  let currentValueIndex=-1;
  this.state.currentValue.map((e,index)=>{
    if(e===event.target.value){
      currentValueIndex=index;
    }
  });
  let list=this.state.list;
  this.setState({currentValue:list[currentValueIndex]}); 
  
  this.filterList();
  this.onGenerate();
  this.setState({isInvisible:false});
}
//if user clicks outside query box
async onClickAway(){
  this.setState({tags:""});
  this.setState({filterList:[]});
  this.setState({isInvisible:true});
}
         //to remove item upon request.
     async removeItem(){
      let path='/region';
      axios.delete(
        'http://localhost:8080'+path+"/"+this.props.id);
      window.location.reload(false);
     }
      
       async componentDidMount() {
        let path='/region';
        let ofObject
        if(this.props.id!==-1){
        await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:8080'+path+"/"+this.props.id)
             .then(res => { ofObject=res.data;
           }).catch(
           function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });}
          else{
            let emptyItem={
              value:"",country:this.props.country
            }
            ofObject=emptyItem;
           
          } await this.setState({region:ofObject});
          console.log(this.state.region);
      } 
      //upon entering the input button edit or save will be completed.
       async handleSubmit(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         let path='/region';
         let ofError="";
         axios.post(
          'http://localhost:8080'+path,this.state.region)
             .then(res => { ofError=res;
           }).catch(
           function (error) {
            let emptyItem="";
            window.location.reload(false);
             ofError=emptyItem;
          });this.setState({regionError:ofError});
     }
    render()
    {
   


           return( <div>

                                          <div> country: {this.state.region.country.name || ''}</div>
                                       <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                                       <div><b>previous value:{this.state.region.value || ''}</b></div>
                                          <label>region:</label>
                                          <Autocomplete list={this.state.filterList} onChangeValue={this.onChange}/>
                                          <div>{this.state.regionError}</div>
                                          <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                                       </form>
                                       <button onClick={this.removeItem}>
                                          Delete
                                        </button>
                                </div>);



  }
}

// Exporting the component
export default Region;
```

The only other component added to my input field in geo search is autocomplete code i copied pasted and slightly modified for my own purposes.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Autocomplete extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array)
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    suggestions: []
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // The active selection's index
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      // The suggestions that match the user's input
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      // Whether or not the suggestion list is shown
      showSuggestions: false,
      // What the user has entered
      userInput: ""
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    let suggestions = this.props.list;
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    this.props.onChangeValue(userInput);
    // Filter our suggestions that don't contain the user's input
    const filteredSuggestions = (suggestions || []).filter(
      suggestion =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );

    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions,
      showSuggestions: true,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  };

  onClick = e => {
    this.props.onChangeValue(e.currentTarget.innerText);

    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
    });
  };

  onKeyDown = e => {
    const { activeSuggestion, filteredSuggestions } = this.state;

    // User pressed the enter key
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        showSuggestions: false,
        userInput: filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]
      });
    }
    // User pressed the up arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion - 1 });
    }
    // User pressed the down arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion + 1 });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,
      state: {
        activeSuggestion,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions,
        userInput
      }
    } = this;

    let suggestionsListComponent;

    if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
      if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <ul className="suggestions">
            {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              let className;

              // Flag the active suggestion with a class
              if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                className = "suggestion-active";
              }

              return (
                <li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                  {suggestion}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <div className="no-suggestions">
            <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

the url to my repo is:https://github.com/JonathanDaboush/realtyKingFrontend.git
sorry this one's so long.

Comment: I see you doing `window.location.reload` in many places, on a page reload the states will be reset.

Comment: i tried removing em that didnt help.